# Type "T?" does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Tags: swift

I have a generic class similar to this one:

```
class C<T: Equatable> {

    let t: T

    init(t: T) { 
        self.t = t
    }

}
```

When I try to wrap `Int?` inside, I get the following error:

```
// ERROR: Type "Int?" does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
let c = C<Int?>(t: nil)
```

A quick test shows that `Int?` indeed is `Equatable`:

```
let a: Int? = 5
let b: Int? = 6

let c = a == b // NO ERROR
```

Maybe I'm just too tired today?

Comment: Because it's optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Int? is NOT Equatable

You required `T` to be `Equatable`.

But you are passing `Int?` (a shorthand notation for `Optional<Int>`) which is not `Equatable`.

### Declaration of Optional

You can verify it looking at the source declaration of `Optional`

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible
```

There is no `Equatable`. Even `_Reflectable` and `NilLiteralConvertible` are **NOT** `Equatable`.

### Your test

So why does **your test** seem to prove that `Int?` is indeed `Equatable`?

```
let a: Int? = 5
let b: Int? = 6

let c = a == b // NO ERROR
```

Actually this does not mean that `Int?` is `Equatable`. Infact you are invoking this function

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

as you can see the function requires `T` to be `Equatable`.
And since `T` and `T?` are **totally different types**, this does not mean that `T?` is `Equatable` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that your generic type can be optional like so:

```
class C<T: Equatable> {
  let t: T?
  init(t: T?) { self.t = t }
}

let c = C<Int>(t: nil)
```